# How can a leader entice the wealthy elite to endanger their heirs against their own interests?

Tags: society, government, politics

Society is controlled by seven noble witch houses, each being present at the dawn of the empire and responsible for increasing it's landmass and making it rich and powerful. Witches are born into these noble houses and trained at the witch academy before graduating to become full mages after years of study. However, like all superpowers before them, it has become content and lax at it's pinnacle of power. The ease of technology and good living has made the elites dependent and  lazy, leading to the output of mediocre witches. This is no doubt apparent in the current batch of children growing up in the world, Generation Zeta. Spoiled, entitled, and unappreciative, they embody the worst qualities of society's ills and has given the elders cause for concern for the future running of the empire.

Fortunately, a solution has been found to this decline. In ancient times, witch initiates would go through a rite of passage called The Harrowing. This was a tradition in which an imitate would be put through a series of challenges, each meant to test the initiate's worthiness in being accepted  as a true witch. The Harrowing revolved around intelligence, magical capability, and determination, and the individual would spend years preparing themselves for this passage. They were quite dangerous and were designed to cull the weak among them, with only the strongest surviving to be accepted among their peers.

This tradition has been pushed to the fringes of society, regarded by advances civilization as a barbaric hold of the past. Granny Weather wax, the current Witch Queen of the nation, seeks to institute this tradition back into society by making The Harrowing a necessary final trial of the witch academy. This would toughen up the descendants of future generations and raise the quality of witches. However, it's one thing to play Hunger Games with the lower classes. The lives of male or female commoners and slaves are worthless and tax deductible, and it is good to keep the masses in line. It's another thing to mandate this among the nobility.

The wealthy elite spend time, money, and effort grooming their children to carry on their legacy. They would see it as not in their best interest to force their kids into this rite of passage that would risk their lives that seem unnecessary to them. Trying to institute this tradition back into society would lead to a rebellion among the one percent that would lead to Weatherwax's overthrow.

How would she be able to work this ancient tradition back into today's society at the witch academy?

Comment: "designed to cull the weak among them" - what is the mortality rate among the participants?

Comment: You might consider the 17th-19th century British, where it was the norm for sons of the upper class to go into the military (as officers, of course), and to purchase their commissions: s://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purchase_of_commissions_in_the_British_Army

Answer (score 1):

It may not be wise to go full-bore, but to have the thing in stages.  For one thing, it's improbable that the exact same magic is required to keep the empire as it was to claim it.  For another, building up consequences lets the houses do part or all.

Legal consequences.  It is best if these are actually historical traditions, or already in the law, but that can be fudged.  Especially since before they became an empire, they almost certainly did more oral transmission of rules.

- The survivors acquire a lot of status, and can ascend to offices that are normally reserved for much older people.  (This can be graduated, if you do it in stages.)
- The houses acquire status for serving the empire and still more for producing a survivor.
- A house must produce a candidate fit for the Harrowing or it loses its status as a house.
- Houses are talked into regarding this as a way to engage in intra-house conflict and remove opponents.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a few ideas, a few of which depend on the houses not being entirely peaceful but looking for a moment to attack and gain another piece of territory.

Idea 1- Each of the seven houses are looking for a way to say 'I'm better than you neener neener neener!' so your Harrowing is just a competition for them to show off with a slight risk of death of maiming.

Idea 2- Each of the houses think that the Harrowing is just a training thing for only them, BUT don't know that every house is doing it. Each thinks they are getting extra training so that they can have their witch be the ultimate weapon if they decide that the empire would be better without the other houses.

Idea 3- Weatherwax forces the houses to participate, either by bribing with money or services or just bluffing about a nuke under their castle.

Idea 4- Not sure the exact shape this will be(like a series of tasks like the goblet of fire or just one long campaign of difficult tasks) but you could have it be graduation day and then 'Whoops, I dropped your (insert object of importance here) into this completely random portal which has disappeared now but leads to the finish line of this dangerous (insert challenge name here)! Better go get it!' and repeat this after each task if its multiple stages.

You could go many different ways with this, and ultimately you pick what's best for your story, which probably isn't one of these. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like she is trying to replace a system based on inheritance with a system based on merit. If she has to convince the elite to participate in the Harrowing, she might need to tweak the reward and punishment system. In other words, she has to create an environment with the right incentives.

For example, what happens to participants who fail? If those who fail have a low chance of dying and can return to their families, maybe she can say something like, "you're no worse off after the Harrowing compared to now, you might even learn new skills and make new friends in the process". Limited risk but unlimited reward.

Alternatively, if high risk is important to the action and suspense in the storyline, she can appeal to the elite's pride and status. Since all elites will be parts of a social network, she can target the densely connected "nodes" and persuade them (appeal to their pride). Then people who are connected to these influential people can be expected to automatically adopt the same worldview or ideology.

Or she can target the heirs directly. If they don't find anything meaningful right now, she can show them how the Harrowing can give them a purpose. Maybe there are monsters that participants must defeat. If they don't, the world as they know it will be forever altered. Or maybe the Harrowing is a selection process for creating an elite team capable of defeating the monsters.

Answer (score 0):

#### Wealthy powerful people respond very well to offers of more wealth and more power.

So... Same way we convince our powerful wealthy elites to support something that makes the world a better place. Offer them more power and wealth in return. You basically need to convince the 1% that there is a 0.1% above them and they'll throw their children into the arena in the rush to get richer or more power.

The winning child is obviously going to be leadership material - so that's how the current queen will pick her line of succession. The successor becomes the new queen, and gets all the wealth of the kingdom, and all the power.